# Density of information/semantic of Chinese and Korean language versus european languages

Tags: semantics, alphabets

Some years ago I had read an interesting article about how much information chinese people could put in one tweet of 140 characters. But I cannot find again this article.

I'm interested in having numbers to compare how much more information can be encoded with fewer signs/characters, like in Chinese, and Korean.

Do you know of a thorough study (maybe statistics?), or in which direction should I search: Is there a field in semantics that goes in this direction ?

e.g. in Chinese: 6 sinograms `中囯大, 日本小` can encode the same information as 22 latin letters in English `China is big, Japan is small` or even 31 in French `La Chine est grande, le Japon est petit`

I have tried to search things about "Semantics Density in Chinese" on google, but search results were not obvious.

I'm also interested in Korean, because the accumulation/contraction of syllables to make words/signs feels similar in the end to a ready-made chinese sinogram (it's my feeling, I have only learned some *very* limited beginner notions of Korean).

I would like these numbers so as to illustrate the interest of a computer programming language based on signs and symbols, so as to convey as much information as possible for the reader/programmer.

Comment: There is the basic _information theory_: a letter/interpunction char has ca 32 possibiltiies, ²log 32 = 5. A sinogram bears more information. Then the information that is actually conveyed etcetera.

Comment: To expand upon the comment above, typing a Korean character usually takes 2 or 3 keystrokes (sometimes up to 5), and in a typical text editor (such as vim) it will take the same space of two Latin characters (otherwise it will look horrible and barely readable). So, if your hypothetical language uses Korean characters, you need to at least double the "information density per character" to break even.

Comment: To add to what @jick said: In information-theoretic terms, choosing between around 8000 sinograms means 13 bits, while choosing between 26 letters plus a few symbols means 5 bits. And practice follows theory here—if you use UTF-8, English takes 8 bits/character, Chinese averages around 23 bits/character (because most sinograms take 3 bytes). This difference is enough to explain most (although not quite all) of the density you're describing: you're talking 20 vs. 28 UTF-8 bytes in your example.

Comment: Also, notice that Chinese writing tends to be more ambiguous than Latin writing. Partly this is inherent: it's why the same string can represent a Mandarin sentence, a Cantonese sentence, and even almost a Japanese sentence (it's missing particles and inflection, but a Japanese reader could easily get "China big, Japan small" out of that). But partly it's because there aren't actually enough sinograms in common use to avoid ambiguity—"中国大" can also mean "Chinese University", while the English string "China big" obviously can't.

Comment: As for your end goal, you might want to look at research into APL and J (a later language which started off as APL in ASCII), and into East Asian teaching languages like ドリトル.

Comment: Oh, also Chinese Applesoft Basic, or whatever it was called. As a kid, I had an Acer clone with a switch between "Apple ROM" and "Chinese", and, despite not knowing Chinese, I played with Chinese mode a lot. From what I remember: Basic keywords are one character (although it often takes 2 Cangjie keystrokes), although stored in memory as the same 1-byte token used in Applesoft. Variables can only be one character (2 keystrokes, and 2 bytes in memory); presumably that's often sufficient for meaningful names. Anyway, it looks something like "入 卜; 印 卜" instead of "INPUT X; PRINT X".

Comment: I looked for info on Asian programming languages like `ドリトル` and Chinese BASIC, but as far as I can tell, nobody ever promoted them for their information density, only for "you can learn programming without learning English" benefits. Which I guess makes sense. But just because I didn't find anything doesn't mean that it isn't out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is really about Chinese vs. English, minimally. But the different valuable comments and the previous answer made me consider the problem differently.

Explained below, I arrive to a ratio between 1/7 and 1/2 when comparing Chinese and English.

That would make me states that the Chinese writing systems conveys between 2 and 7 more information than written English. I'm not sure if I can call this ratio "semantic density".

That can be a concrete example, an insight to express the power of existing meaning-oriented writting systems compared to existing phonetic-oriented systems.

---

First impression is that sheer information theory is much too large, in the sense that it explores all given possibility to encode information through one expression system (if I understood correctly). I prefer to restrict on existing and commonly used systems such as human languages.

The references to information theory however made me think about average length of words in languages, and how much words are needed to express a given information.

The numbers I have grasped so far are really rough approximations:

1. from this [link](http://www.ravi.io/language-word-lengths): average length of English words is 8.2
2. from this [link](https://www.proz.com/forum/business_issues/53938-character_to_word_ratio_for_chn_jpn_and_kor_to_english.html): most chinese words are 2 characters/signs long. But also those two estimations which differ greatly:

   - 100 Chinese signs = 170 english words
   - 170-210 Chinese signs = 100 English words

So we can roughly says:

1. 100 * 2 = 200 chinese characters for 170 x 8.2 english words = 1400   => ratio 1/7
2. 200 * 2 = 400 chinese characters for 820 english words              => ratio 1/2

I'll try to refine those estimation. But I will use these numbers merely for illustration anyway. Because I'm sure I could be asked why I've chosen to base the core fundations of that programming language on 1-char signs.

These signs corpus has to be limited, because like Chinese, you have to know the signs so as to understand them. It's a real cognitive cost.

Comment: That last point is important—and also, you have to know how to enter the signs, and how to look them up in a manual (think of Chinese dictionaries sorted by stroke order and radical), and you have to be able to (rapidly and accurately) distinguish them visually, and so on. All of that is probably part of the reason Chinese has only a few thousand symbols instead of half a million, and everyday computational Chinese even fewer than newspaper Chinese (and earlier computational systems like Canjie had even fewer), and so on.

Comment: For the moment I rely on vim digraphs. But the issue of a more general input mechanism is a real subject.

Comment: You have to make your measure dependent on time, not just space. Parsing a 7 letter word doesn't take longer and I'm biased to think it's even quicker. Whereas for space, the question should be how much differentiable info can be put in a 10pt square. Then you should wonder whether purely sequential layout were optimal for programming. As for spoken language, the lexicon is a different matter. *There are only two hard problems in computer science*, as they say, cache locality and naming.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a study on the question you're asking, but I do have some information to add—and possibly a better way to approach the [X in your XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

---

First, let's look at your example:

> in Chinese: 6 sinograms `中囯大, 日本小` can encode the same information as 22 latin letters in English `China is big, Japan is small`

The number of sinograms in an average literate Chinese native is somewhere in the ballpark of 8000, while English only has 26 letters (plus a few symbols, in both cases, but let's ignore symbols and spaces, as you already have). This means that, in information theoretic terms, each sinogram represents about 13.0 bits, each letter about 4.7. So we're really talking about 78 bits vs. 103 bits here, which is not nearly as dramatic as 6 vs. 22 characters.

Presumably the total information is important to production and processing costs. You can see this in other ways, too—the sinograms have much more relevant visual detail; it's presumably more costly to distinguish "大" from "小" than "g" from "l". This also means that people often double-width characters and/or larger fonts for reading Chinese on the screen.

Meanwhile, Chinese writing tends to be more ambiguous than Latin writing. Partly this is inherent to the way Chinese writing is used,<sup>1</sup> But also, there aren't enough sinograms in common use to avoid homographs and other forms of ambiguity as much as English orthography does. For example, "中国大" can also mean "Chinese University", while the English string "China is big" obviously can't. This is presumably not an accident: Chinese writing strikes a pretty good balance for writing Chinese (and Japanese and Korean), but the same balance probably isn't right for a programming language.

So, I think your intuition may be misleading you here. It's still worth looking for research into the information density of the two orthographies (which, again, I don't have), but I don't know that it will tell you as much as you think it will.

---

Meanwhile, since your actual goal is to produce a "computer programming language based on signs and symbols", you may be better off looking at programming languages in the first place, instead of trying to draw analogies with natural languages.

---

Starting close to where you're already looking, there's [Chinese BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_BASIC), a family of variants of Applesoft BASIC using Chinese instead of English characters.

In Applesoft BASIC, each BASIC keyword is stored in-memory as a single-byte token, but displayed, and entered, as a word like "PRINT" or "INPUT". Variables can be as many letters as you want, but only the first two characters are significant.

In Chinese BASIC, each keyword is displayed and entered as a single sinogram like "印" or "入". That obviously takes a lot less room on the screen than 5 letters, and is arguably easier to process. And, while you only have a few hundred sinograms for variable names, you can still pack in a lot more useful information than 2 letters can—especially since there are good variable names beginning with most of those sinograms, but not many good variable names beginning with, say, "QX".

This is purely anecdotal, but as a kid who didn't even speak Chinese, I flipped my Acer switchable Apple ][ clone over to the Chinese ROM quite often. In part that was about saving keystrokes,<sup>2</sup> but being able to find a character that looked like what it meant while only taking up less valuable real estate (remember, this was a 40x24 screen) was also definitely part of it.

---

But I think you'll find more research around Ken Iverson's language [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)).

APL added custom symbols for operators and functions. This allowed people to use actual mathematical symbols like `÷` instead of having to map them to whatever's lying around in ASCII, but it also allowed a much larger number of operators and functions to be written as a single symbol. And adding the idea of "inflections" (which roughly parallel written Japanese verbs, written with a kanji root followed by zero or more kana) allows a huge number of things to be written with just a couple of symbols. For example, things that would take a nested for loop in FORTRAN may just take an extra `/` character in APL. The Wikipedia article has some good examples (picking 6 lottery numbers with `x[⍋x←6?40]`, finding primes in quadratic time with `(~R∊R∘.×R)/R←1↓ιR`, etc.).

APL was mainly about array processing. Another way to make languages terser comes from functional programming. John Backus's language [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_(programming_language)) had similar single-symbol, non-ASCII operators for composing functions, lifting functions, etc., allowing what in modern terms is called [point-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) style.

Obviously this terseness has costs in comprehensibility, not just benefits. But let's pretend it's pure benefit. How much of that benefit comes from the extra symbols?

A later language by Iverson (and Roger Hui), [J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_(programming_language)), merges APL and FP into a single language, giving you array-processing and functional conciseness and convenience in a single language. But J dropped APL's symbols. The most common operators and functions are a single ASCII character, but the rest are two characters. To make this work, they added a lot more inflections. Adding `/` to any symbol still means to fold that symbol's function, but you can also add, e.g., `:`, with a meaning that extends the symbol in a way that's only quasi-regular. (For example, `=:` turns equality into assignment, while `/:` turns folding into sorting.)

I don't know how much research went into making this decision. I don't even know why it was made—whether Iverson believes J is easier to comprehend, or that it's a bit harder but still a good tradeoff (so much easier to input, transmit over ASCII channels, typeset for printing, etc.). But there's probably a lot of information out there if you search for it.

---

<sub>1. It's why the same string can represent a Mandarin sentence, a Cantonese sentence, and even almost a Japanese sentence (it's missing particles and inflection, but a Japanese reader could easily get "China big, Japan small" out of that).</sub>

<sub>2. Computers like the Sinclair ZX81 and calculators like the HP 48S let you enter a full keyword with two keystrokes. The Apple ][ made you type all five letters and a space, but in Chinese mode, you could enter "印" as two keystrokes (using the Canjie input method), just like a Sinclair or HP.</sub>

Comment: On further thought, if this is a good answer to the question, the question probably belongs on some other SE site (not SO, but… maybe Programming?), possibly with a bit of rewriting first. I don't want to delete the answer and flag the question to be moved, but it might be worth writing a question about research into symbolic programming languages and posting it on another site instead of relying on a semi-off-topic answer on Linguistics.

Comment: IDEs for agda, coq and the like try to represent mathematical formulas closer to actual mathematical notation, with some success. IMHO, the fixation on sequential text is, in the age of hypertext, a red herring. IDEs already provide many visual programming features and grasping a big program without such tools is well difficult. And then just look at this page, it's full of color and illustration. By the way, Ruby is a language famous for *syntax sugar*, written by a Japanese, and recently rivaled by Elixir as far as syntax goes.

Comment: With variable bitrate coding like UTF-8, you can have a bit string of variable length between 8 and 24 bits represent the better part of the whole english lexicon uniquely, or a string of 8 to 16b to represent 8000 chinese characters (of over 100,000; 4000 is a rough limit for literacy). "Text information density" is simply not well defined, is it? We do productively read on the word level, after all.

Comment: @vectory Wolfram lets you display and even edit equations graphically, but for non-trivial edits to large equations people still usually drop down to editing the textual form. This may just be because programmers have a text habit that’s hard to break (but should be broken), but it may be because navigating around something that isn’t a square grid without leaving the keyboard is still a poorly solved problem. There’s probably research on that, which might help the OP, but I don’t know where.

Comment: @vectory There are also languages that let you go even farther, representing control flow as a visually-editable graph, but even children using (the Squeak one I forget the name of) as their first language who become proficient seem to end up pulling up the textual Smalltalk to edit the control flow, which implies that after 3 decades of research in visual programming, we still haven't had the breakthrough that will allow it to take off.

Comment: @vectory Finally, I don't know what your point is with UTF-8. Information theoretic density is certainly well defined, and explained well enough even in Shannon's original paper. The efficiency of a particular encoding is more complicated, and probably not relevant here, but you can easily measure (and reasonably well predict) the bits per character that are needed for a particular corpus. For UTF-8 you usually get around 8.0 for English vs. 22.9 for Chinese; UTF-16, 16.0 vs. 16.6. But obviously that's different for a corpus of, e.g., English with lots of emoji.

Comment: @vectory One more thing, for Ruby: Most of the syntactic sugar isn't about using 
symbols in place of text; it's about allowing you to build new control flow forms out of new words (methods names), which all use the same set of small symbols (`()|.`) in fixed ways. Mats explicitly rejected the idea of adding new symbols a la APL, or user-definable operators a la Haskell—he even (differing from most other Unicode-friendly languages, like Python) put the Unicode math symbols pages into the identifier space, so `x÷y` is an identifier name, not an operation on identifiers `x` and `y`.

Comment: When you say UTF-8 you mean unicode, the assignment of Akkadian cuniform, emojis and other symbols to a specific encoding. If you instead assigned the English or Chinese lexicon to the code points, the information density should come out a lot closer.

Comment: @vectory UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding. If you used the same algorithm for a different character set, it wouldn't be UTF-8. And there wouldn't be much reason to use that algorithm. It's far from the densest way to encode 1.1M characters; it's used for _other_ reasons, starting with the fact that it can encode all ASCII characters with a single byte that equals the ASCII character (which would be useless if Unicode didn't start with ASCII, and if it weren't frequently used to encode a lot of source code, English text, ASCIIfied foreign text, ASCIImath, etc.).

Comment: @vectory But if you want to know the actual information density of a character set, you don't need to invent a practical encoding for them, just use Shannon's formula directly. If you're treating them as uniformly distributed, it's just log2(number of characters in the set), hence the 13.0 vs. 4.7 in my answer. If you have a non-uniform distribution, you build a Hammond code out of the distribution and then log2 that.

Comment: Oh OK, I was assuming for sake of the argument that 8 bit log stepping would approach the distribution reasonably well. You are still comparing word forms to characters, oranges to apples. Shannon's method concerns data transmission, not semantic information, but that was specifically asked for. In a sense, since English doesn't put as much burden of interpretation on the reader--I mean if Chinese has 8000 common signs that can compose I don't know how many diglyphs--it would be denser in information, less ambiguous. You hypothesized as much.

Comment: @vectory 8-bit stepping might approach the distribution reasonably well, but it's still an extra complexity that's harder to calculate correctly and adds nothing. Why not just measure directly in bits? (You can always divide everything by 8 if it's easier to think of that way.) And adding UTF-8 encoding on top of stepping just makes it even more complicated, and more inaccurate, for even less benefit.

Comment: @vectory And I'm definitely not comparing word forms to characters. Chinese words often take 1 character, but also often take 2. English words usually take more than 1 character, but occasionally take only 1 ("a"). I'm comparing Chinese to English character by character, because that's what the OP asked for, and it makes sense. For the rest of your comment—I've already got two paragraphs and a footnote in the answer explaining what I think you're trying to say here. Is there something you're trying to add or clarify?

Comment: I think I added an illustrative example and the claim that OP's question lacks meaning (not devoid if meaning, but lacking a thorough understanding of Chinese).